# Listen for client side router (react router) to finish loading a new route in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, react-router, react-router-dom

I am building a chrome extension that adds features to an existing website that uses react router. I am able to handle the initial load but every subsequent load is difficult since there doesn't appear to be an event I can listen to for when the new route has finished loading. Currently, I am using a service worker to message the content script when the URL of the tab changes but that doesn't account for the time it takes to load the new page. The crucial part about this is that I am not the owner of the site I am modifying so I can't add anything to the code to make this easier, I'm just working with what's given to me.

I am currently using a MutationObserver on the react router root component to check for the page load following the URL change but it is clunky and inconsistent since it doesn't work for all routes. Is there a better way to go about this? Is there an event I can listen for or a specific quirk of the router that I can use to make this snappier? I am basically just looking to create my own callback function for when the router **finishes** loading the new page.

Comment: I don't think `react-router` has much of anything to do with what the component code that is mounted and rendered does once it has done its part to match the URL and render the appropriate route element. Is listening to the route/URL path change not sufficient enough? Can you share more about what isn't working for you, what you need to solve for?

Comment: @DrewReese Listening to the URL change works fine, although there is a delay between when the URL changes and when the router content actually gets changed (seems to be due to a network request). If I change the content as soon as the URL changes, it will modify the previous route which will get swapped out shortly after when the request is resolved. I'm not super familiar with react-router so I'm not totally sure if that network request functionality is a part of the router or just the specific site I'm working on...